# ORA-00449: background process 'MMON' unexpectedly terminated with error 448

Tags: oracle

I got the follwing error while running a query from Java:

```
The database returned the following error:
[Oracle] #11 ORA-00449: background process 'MMON' unexpectedly terminated with error 448
[Oracle] #11 
Database Error State: S1000
Database Error Code: 449
```

The following are the exception generated by compiler:

```
Report Error [615] The database returned the following error: [Oracle] #11 ORA-00449: background process 'MMON' unexpectedly terminated with error 448
[Oracle] #11 
Database Error State: S1000
Database Error Code: 449
    at com.inet.report.ReportExceptionFactory.createReportExceptionWithCause(SourceFile:165)
    at com.inet.report.ReportExceptionFactory.createReportExceptionWithCause(SourceFile:230)
    at com.inet.report.cr.oE(SourceFile:1422)
    at com.inet.report.cr.run(SourceFile:1357)
    at com.inet.report.renderer.thread.b.a(SourceFile:104)
    at com.inet.report.renderer.thread.b$b.run(SourceFile:227)
Caused by: Report Error [615] The database returned the following error: [Oracle] #11 ORA-00449: background process 'MMON' unexpectedly terminated with error 448
[Oracle] #11 
Database Error State: S1000
Database Error Code: 449
    at com.inet.report.ReportExceptionFactory.createReportException(SourceFile:95)
    at com.inet.report.ReportExceptionFactory.createReportExceptionWithCause(SourceFile:197)
    at com.inet.report.ReportExceptionFactory.createReportExceptionWithCause(SourceFile:230)
    at com.inet.report.Database.getReportData(SourceFile:2580)
    at com.inet.report.cf.b(SourceFile:219)
    at com.inet.report.dl.b(SourceFile:1628)
    at com.inet.report.dl.a(SourceFile:1610)
    at com.inet.report.cr.oC(SourceFile:1083)
    at com.inet.report.cr.run(SourceFile:1209)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: com.inet.ora.Ora4SQLException: [Oracle] #11 ORA-00449: background process 'MMON' unexpectedly terminated with error 448
[Oracle] #11 
    at com.inet.ora.aj.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.inet.ora.ax.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.inet.ora.ax.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.inet.ora.ax.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.inet.ora.bj.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.inet.report.rowsource.q.a(SourceFile:161)
    at com.inet.report.rowsource.q.<init>(SourceFile:42)
    at com.inet.report.dv.b(SourceFile:169)
    at com.inet.report.dv.a(SourceFile:155)
    at com.inet.report.Database.a(SourceFile:3270)
    at com.inet.report.Database.getReportData(SourceFile:2575)
    ... 7 more
```

Please tell me what is the exact cause of this and also tell me the solution for it.

Comment: There will be an entry in the alert.log with the cause, plus (probably) an associated trace file. Please edit your question with the alert.log entry.

Comment: @Naims which is the database version? this looks like a bug. I can make a search if you give me more data.